SPL Token with Tokenomic on Solana
I need to know about creating tokenomics for a token on Solana. I'm attempting to mint an SPL token in 2020 or 2022 with tokenomics, where I determine the public supply, marketing, and development percentages, similar to SafeMoon on Ethereum. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to achieve this?
